# ipc Renderer says it's not a function even though I think I'm using it correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I'm trying to write simple text editor with Electrion and Vue.js, but when I'm trying to handle Ipc event in code it throws an error in the console and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the function

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    ipcRenderer.on('NEW_DOCUMENT_NEEDED', () => {
        console.log("test");
    });
  });
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Error in nextTick: "TypeError: electron__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default.a.on is not a function"
```

[Here's source article](https://memorytin.com/2018/07/26/electronjs-vue-js-setting-up-ipcrenderer-event-handlers/)

I'm just a beginner.

Comment: How are you importing ``ipcRenderer``?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Switching from import to require fixed the issue <3